# Concatenate Character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to add a character to `order_id` column. The table below shows what I intend to achieve:

```
Add_field   Order_id    New_column
0              32639    032639
0              37378    037378
```

The result I want to achieve for each row is stored in `New_column`.

Comment: What are you really trying to do - do you want your order ID to be a string holding a zero-padded six-character version of the current value? Are you trying to store that modified value in a table, or just add the leading zero(s) while querying?

Comment: Let me give you a clue. This `select '00'||'11'||'22' as col from dual` would produce `001122`. you can use `|` to concatenate strings in oracle.

Comment: What are the data types of `ADD_FIELD`, `ORDER_ID`, and `NEW_COLUMN`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Sql query for concat column values in result

```
SELECT  CONCAT(column1, ' ', column2) as columnName 
FROM tableName
```

Here (column1, ' ', column2) you can change ' ' according your requirement.

Comment: Actually, column1 (Add_field) is not in the database.

Comment: @OluAkin - so where is it coming from? Is it always a zero?

Comment: So you can add in code like in php by concatenation operator(.) then can assign in a variable.

Comment: @AlexPoole it will always be zero

Comment: `concat` function in oracle has only two parameters. This would work with mysql but not in oracle.Why don't use `|` to concat instead? CMIIW.

Comment: @RubahMalam I got an error message "inconsistent data types: expected CHAR got NUMBER"

Comment: @OluAkin Then you need to convert number column into char before concatenate.

Comment: @OluAkin Why do you want to add 0 to the beginning of your column? What is the reason behind this requirement?

Comment: I  used CONCAT('0', CAST(order_id AS VARCHAR(6))) but it is still returning the same error "inconsistent data types: expected CHAR got NUMBER"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select '0' || TO_CHAR(column1)
from yourTable
```

**Example:**

You can try (table indipendent):

```
select '0' || TO_CHAR(rownum)
from dual
union
select '0' || TO_CHAR(3)
from dual
union
select '0' || TO_CHAR('4')
from dual;
```

output will be:

```
01
03
04
```

Comment: Error "inconsistent data types: expected CHAR got NUMBER"

Comment: Can you tell me the type of your column?

Comment: @OluAkin - I don't think it's possible to get that error from that expression, whatever the column data type.. Are you sure it isn't coming from another part of the query?